# How to handle synchronize (rsync) permission errors in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

We got `Permission Denied` error when using `rsync` via `synchronize` module in Ansible, using sysadmin account, that's an administrative account. Using a remote account, the owner of the destination directories and files, ended with the same result.

**Command**

```bash
ansible-playbook -u sysadmin -i ./inventories/hosts scripts-sync.yml -K
```

**`scripts-sync.yml`**

```yaml
- name: Copy scripts to batch server
  synchronize:
    src: scripts
    dest: /dest/scripts/
    recursive: true
```

**Error Message**

```yaml
fatal: [batch]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "/usr/bin/rsync --delay-updates -F --compress --archive --rsh='/usr/bin/ssh -S none -i /data/ansible/key -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null' --out-format='<<CHANGED>>%i %n%L' /data/ansible/scripts/ sysadmin@10.104.XX.XX:/dest/scripts/", "msg": "Warning: Permanently added '10.104.XX.XX' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\nrsync: failed to set times on \"/dest/scripts/\": Operation not permitted (1)\nrsync: failed to set times on \"/dest/scripts/batch\": Operation not permitted (1)\nrsync: recv_generator: mkdir \"/dest/scripts/docs\" failed: Permission denied (13)\n*** Skipping any contents from this failed directory ***\nrsync: failed to set times on \"/dest/scripts/tests\": Operation not permitted (1)\nrsync: connection unexpectedly closed (1748 bytes received so far) [sender]\nrsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.2]\n", "rc": 12}
```

I imagine this error caused by that administrative account has no permission to change the timestamp of the destination files.

Is there an options or setting to achieve `rsync` not to change the account and owner of the destination files?

**Additional Info**

We found destination directory had the other owner's hidden files, made by CI/CD pipeline tool. Also confirmed `rsync` command has been successfully, as long as we don't set `-t` (timestamp) and `-p` (permission) options, changed options from `--archive` (`--rlptgoD`) to `-rlgoD`.

```bash
rsync --delay-updates -F --compress -rlgoD --rsh='/usr/bin/ssh -S none -i /data/ansible/key -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null' --out-format='<<CHANGED>>%i %n%L' /data/ansible/scripts/ sysadmin@10.104.XX.XX:/dest/scripts/
```

Is there any option in Ansible `synchronize` module same as `-rlgoD`?

Comment: please show the permission of the destination files and source files

Comment: @isilia Many thanks for your kind comment. We noticed the other owners hidden files in destination directory and confirmed rsync command worked without some rsync-options. If you knowany options in Ansible synchronize, same with "-rlgoD" (no timestamp and no permission), please let me know.

Comment: From the ansible tag:  installing ansible and prerequisites, connection issues... are off-topic. rsync, too, is a utility and this is not a programming question. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: According the documentation [Examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/synchronize_module.html#examples) you could try to add `rsync_opts: --` with your required options.